# DataDog dashboard can expose part of metrics path as tag?

Tags: datadog, datadog-dashboard

I have several services that emit DataDog metrics named like:

- `app.service1.outgoing_requests.latency`
- `app.service2.outgoing_requests.latency`
- `app.serviceN.outgoing_requests.latency`

This is inconvenient to query:  I'd like the 2nd segment to be available as a tag on a combined metric:  eg `app.services.outgoing_requests.latency`, with tags `service:service1`, `service:service2`, ..

Is this possible via DataDog configuration, or do I need to change code for all my services to emit the metrics / tags I want?